# chrome.webrequest in a event listener function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrequest, event-listener

I'm trying to start the webrequest listener when you click a start button in the extension. However, it's not working. When I add the webrequest listener outside the function, it works however. Here's my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "SimplyFocused",
  "description": "This extension will stop procrastination.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "options_page": "options.html",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simply Focused</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="background.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="popup">
      <button class="btn btn-default" id="start">Start</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', startBlock);
    });
```

**background.js**

```
 if (localStorage.getItem("blocked") == null) {
        localStorage.setItem("blocked", JSON.stringify([]));
    }

    function startBlock() {
        var blockedSites = ["*://www.yahoo.com/*"];
        console.log(blockedSites);
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
            function(details){console.log(details); return {cancel: true};},
            {urls: ["*://www.yahoo.com/*"]},
            ["blocking"]);
    }

    // chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    //  function(details){console.log(details); return {cancel: true};},
    //  {urls: ["*://www.yahoo.com/*"]},
    //  ["blocking"]);
```

When I uncomment the comment part in background.js, the blocking works. I'm guess it has to do with webrequest not being even based but I'm not sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popup and background are not the same pages. Try to access background's `startBlock` function using [`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage) method:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().startBlock();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That works. I'm new to javascript, what happens in my original code? Because it was logging the blockedSites but it wasn't adding the listener.

Comment: Think of popup and background as about basically different pages. So there is no function `startBlock` in popup "window".